# Swift: Add done, next, previous functions in toolbar

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add the function next provious and done but i don't know. Please help me because I am new in swift. Here is the code:

```
var inputToolbar: UIToolbar = {
    var toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = .default
    toolbar.isTranslucent = true
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .bordered, target: self, action: Selector("doneButtonAction"))
    var flexibleSpaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var fixedSpaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    var nextButton  = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "1"), style: .bordered, target: self, action:Selector(("nextButtonAction")))
    nextButton.width = 13.0

    var previousButton  = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "2"), style: .bordered, target: self, action: Selector("previousButtonAction"))
    previousButton.width = 13.0
    toolbar.setItems([fixedSpaceButton, nextButton, fixedSpaceButton, previousButton, flexibleSpaceButton, doneButton], animated: true)
    toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return toolbar
}()
func doneButtonAction()
    {
       // here should be the code for Done button
    }
func nextButtonAction()
    {
       // here should be the code for Next button
    }
func previousButtonAction()
    {
       // here should be the code for Previous button
    }
 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

       percentageField.inputAccessoryView = inputToolbar
    valueField.inputAccessoryView = inputToolbar
}
```

[The design is OK now i need actions to be functional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwpIv.png)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension UIViewController {
    func addInputAccessoryForTextFields(textFields: [UITextField], dismissable: Bool = true, previousNextable: Bool = false) {
        for (index, textField) in textFields.enumerated() {
            let toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
            toolbar.sizeToFit()

            var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
            if previousNextable {
                let previousButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "prevArrow"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
                previousButton.width = 30
            if textField == textFields.first {
                previousButton.isEnabled = false
            } else {
                previousButton.target = textFields[index - 1]
                previousButton.action = #selector(UITextField.becomeFirstResponder)
            }

            let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "nextArrow"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
                nextButton.width = 30
            if textField == textFields.last {
               nextButton.isEnabled = false
            } else {
                nextButton.target = textFields[index + 1]
                nextButton.action = #selector(UITextField.becomeFirstResponder)
            }
            items.append(contentsOf: [previousButton, nextButton])
            }

            let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
            items.append(contentsOf: [spacer, doneButton])


            toolbar.setItems(items, animated: false)
            textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        }
    }
}
```

In your `viewDidLoad()` add this

```
addInputAccessoryForTextFields(textFields: [textFld1, textFld2, textFld3, textFld4], dismissable: true, previousNextable: true)
```

Comment: You put the extension outside of your class right? I'm running it in Xcode 9.4.1 with swift 4 and I don't have that error

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i want to go in next cell   how to do

Answer (score 2):

Made few changes in your code. For `inputToolbar` check below code:

```
var inputToolbar: UIToolbar = {
    var toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = .default
    toolbar.isTranslucent = true
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    //Removed bordered because it's deprecated. And corrected all selectors for all buttons
    var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonAction))
    var flexibleSpaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var fixedSpaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    //Set image instead of title here
    var nextButton  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "left", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(previousButtonAction))
    nextButton.width = 13.0

    var previousButton  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "right", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(nextButtonAction))
    previousButton.width = 13.0
    toolbar.setItems([fixedSpaceButton, nextButton, fixedSpaceButton, previousButton, flexibleSpaceButton, doneButton], animated: true)
    toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return toolbar
}()
```

Now for the helper function add `@objc` before `func` to make `#selector` working.

check update code with working functionality.

```
@objc func doneButtonAction()
{
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
@objc func nextButtonAction()
{
    if let selectedRange = percentageField.selectedTextRange {

        // and only if the new position is valid
        if let newPosition = percentageField.position(from: selectedRange.start, offset: 1) {

            // set the new position
            percentageField.selectedTextRange = percentageField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
        }
    }
}
@objc func previousButtonAction()
{
    if let selectedRange = percentageField.selectedTextRange {

        // and only if the new position is valid
        if let newPosition = percentageField.position(from: selectedRange.start, offset: -1) {

            // set the new position
            percentageField.selectedTextRange = percentageField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
        }
    }
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    percentageField.inputAccessoryView = inputToolbar
    return true
}
```

In your `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method you have two `textField` so you need to manage which `textField` is tapped. And according to that you can manage `nextButtonAction` and `previousButtonAction` method.

here you can see the result:

[image]

And [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=14273214468295734200) is demo project for more info.